# Angular (4): Custom Error Handler & DI: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to inject an Angular Material 2 element into a custom error handler I wrote, but I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

This is the error handler class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    //FIXME: display popup
    console.error('Error occurred!');
    console.error(error);
    this.snackBar.open('Application Error: ' + error, 'X', {
      duration: environment.snackBarTime,
    });
  }

}
```

This is the providers part of app.module

```
providers: [
    SearchService,
    CompanyService,
    MdSnackBar,
    PopupService,
    AuthService,
    LoginService,
    AuthGuard,
    ErrorService,
    TokenStorageService,
    BankService,
    CountryService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have to manually call the injector with the service name in the execution of the handleError function.

So I had to use the built in `Inject` to inject my service dependency. The end result of the `custom-error-handler` class which calls the `PopupService` which has the `MdSnackBar` dependency injected looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    console.log(error);
    const popupService = this.injector.get(PopupService);   
  }

}
```

And this is the PopupService:

```
@Injectable()
export class PopupService {

  constructor(private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
  }

  public throwErrorPopup(textOfError: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(textOfError, 'X', {
      duration: environment.snackBarTime,
    });
  }

}
```

Solution mentioned in here: https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c

Comment: Did you have any problem with AOT compilation?

Comment: No. Didn't have on Ng 4 and on Ng 5 is also running fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I was injecting the service inside it's own constructor. I committed this noob mistake while copying a code. if it helps any one like me.

```
export class AskLanguageProvider {
  public selectedLang = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public storage: Storage,
    private lan: AskLanguageProvider, // <= The culprit
    public translate: TranslateService) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer for me isn't working and for me appears no Provider error. But i found different approach how to achieve this.

From app.module.ts constructor i am calling WampService setter method, which one needs to include WampErrorHandler service.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private wampService: WampService) {
    this.wampService.setErrorHandler(WampErrorHandler);
  }
}
```

But in WampService setErrorHandler method looks like this:

```
    setErrorHandler(handler) {
        this.wampErrorHandler = this.injector.get(handler)
    };
```

Also I am using Injector in constructor:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
```